# Geometric figures such that all sets of $n$ points are similar to some subset of the figure

Tags: geometry

Maybe (probably) this has been studied before, but I had a hard time figuring out what search terms to use, so I thought I’d ask here. I’m interested in questions of this form:

> Let $S$ be a set where each element is a finite set of points in the plane. (We could also consider higher dimensions but I’ve just been thinking about 2D.)
>
> Let $F$ be a set of points in the plane. We say $F$ is a *stem figure* of $S$ if every element of $S$ is similar to some subset of $F$. Further, $F$ is a *minimal stem figure* of $S$ if any strict subset of $F$ is not a stem figure of $S$. (Using the name “stem figure” as an analog of stem cell, until I think of a better name or learn that one already exists.)
>
> For some set $S$, find a (minimal) stem figure of $S$.

For example, let $A_3^*$ be the set containing every set of three non-collinear points. Then any circle $C$ is a stem figure of $A_3^*$. (For any triangle, draw the circumcircle; any transformation taking that circle to $C$ will take the triangle to a similar subset of $C$.)

However, (I believe) a circle is not a *minimal* stem figure of $A_3^*$. You can remove some parts of it and still contain subsets similar to everything in $A_3^*$. But I do think (although I haven’t proven) that a $240^\circ$ circular arc with closed ends is a minimal stem figure of $A_3^*$.

If we consider $A_3$, the set of *all* sets of three points — including collinear ones — then the union of a $240^\circ$ arc and any line segment is a stem figure, since sets of collinear points can be placed on the line. This type of figure can’t be minimal, since the line segment could always be made shorter. However, you could also just add a single point outside of the circle, and collinear points can be placed so that two are on the circle and the third is on this extra point. If it’s in the right region, all sets of 3 collinear points are covered, and the arc + point would be a minimal stem figure, I think. Similarly, I think a ray $\overrightarrow{AB}$ along with a point $P$ such that $\angle PAB = 60^\circ$ (or something along those lines) is a minimal stem figure for $A_3$.

For $A_4$, the set of all sets of four points, the union of a circle and a ray extending from the center is a stem figure. (If all four points are collinear, put them on the ray; otherwise, you can scale/move the shape so three of them are on the circle, then rotate it so the fourth is on the ray.) I don’t think it actually has to be a ray: I’m guessing a radius would also work, based on an intuition that given any four non-collinear points, there must be one that is inside the circumcircle of the other three. But maybe that intuition is wrong.

Some things I’d like to know:

- Are the conjectures I’ve made about certain sets being (minimal) stem figures true?
- Are all closed curves stem figures for $A_3^*$?
- What are all the minimal stem figures for $A_3$? $A_4$? If there are infinitely many, can they be classified into finitely many families?
- What about $A_n$ (the set of all sets of $n$ points) for $n>4$? Is it possible to have a stem figure for any of these sets that doesn’t have a disk as a subset?

Does anyone know of any articles or resources that discuss these questions? I’ve been having fun thinking about this myself but I’d be curious to see what others have found too, if anything.